# How to get the string after the first numerical?

Tags: shell, regular-expression

I have a string structure like this `bob-type-8.2-mp2-2017-93-43-11-65-48.spr` form where I just need to extract `8.2-mp2-2017-93-43-11-65-48` .

It means the output string should contain all the characters after encountering the first numerical value and then removing the `.spr` from that.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**:

```
echo "bob-type-8.2-mp2-2017-93-43-11-65-48.spr" | sed 's/^[^0-9]*//;s/\.[^.]*$//'
```

Output will:

```
8.2-mp2-2017-93-43-11-65-48
```

**Explanation**:

Sed uses pattern '`s/pattern/replace_pattern/'` to find `pattern` and replace it to `replace_pattern`

So, pattern `'s/^[^0-9]*//'` get all symbols from start of line and before first digits occurance and replace it to nothing (`replace_pattern` are empty).

The next step - delete extention. We can do this with the same sed's pattern `'s///'`.

`s/\.[^.]*$//` - find all symbols that not a `.` at the end `$` of line and replace it to nothing.

`;` - devide patterns.

For best understanding you could use this command instead:

```
echo "bob-type-8.2-mp2-2017-93-43-11-65-48.spr" | sed -e 's/^[^0-9]*//' -e 's/\.[^.]*$//'
```

Comment: Note that it assumes the file name doesn't contain newline characters (or bytes not forming valid characters, or backslash characters depending on the echo implementation)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

`echo bob-type-8.2-mp2-2017-93-43-11-65-48.spr | sed -r 's/^[^0-9]*(.*)\..*$/\1/'`

This takes everything from the first numerical value encountered after the beginning of the string to the end of the string minus the last dot and what follows it.

- `^[^0-9]*` skips all non-numerical: NOT zero to nine (`[^0-9]`), 0 to N times (`*`), from the beginning of the line (`^`).
- `\..*$` matches any character (`.`), 0 to N times (`*`), before the end of the line (`$`), and preceeded by a dot (`\.`). In our case this is `.spr` but it could apply to any other "dot + N-characters" file extension: `.s`, `.yaythatsacoolextension`, etc, work as well.
- `(.*)`, referred as `\1` later, keeps (this is the purpose of the parenthesis, we couldn't refer to it later otherwise) what's in the middle: any character (`.`), 0 to N times (`*`). This gives us `8.2-mp2-2017-93-43-11-65-48`.

So if you need to list into a file the normalized names of all `.spr` contained in the current directory, for example, you can do something like this:

```
for i in *.spr
do
    echo $i | sed -r 's/^[^0-9]*(.*)\..*$/\1/' >> mylist.lst
done
```

And tomorrow, should you need to do that with `.blop` files instead, just turn the `*.spr`above into `*.blop`.

Answer (score 1):

another approach with `sed`.

```
sed 's/^[^[[:digit:]]*\(.*\)\.spr$/\1/' <<<"bob-type-8.2-mp2-2017-93-43-11-65-48.spr"
```

- `^[^[[:digit:]]*` match everything start from beginning of the string until first digit seen; Same as `^[^0-9]*`
- `\(.*\)` matches everything after above matches and parentheses `\(...\)` are used to capture a group match with `\1` as its [back-reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html).
- `\.spr$` matches a literal point followed by `spr` at the end of input string.
- `\1` prints only captured group match.

Answer (score 1):

In Bash, with [`extglob`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob):

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ var=bob-type-8.2-mp2-2017-93-43-11-65-48.spr
$ res=${var##*([^0-9])}
$ res=${res%.spr}
$ echo "$res"
8.2-mp2-2017-93-43-11-65-48
```

`*([^0-9])` matches any string of non-digits, `${var##pattern}` removes the longest matching pattern from the beginning of the string, `${var%pattern}` removes the (shortest) matching pattern from the end.

Answer (score 1):

So many `sed` answers! How about a pure bash solution using `=~` pattern matching and the not-so-common back-reference array `BASH_REMATCH`?

```
# put your string in variable named 'input'
patt='^[^0-9]*(.*)\..*' && [[ $input =~ $patt ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Just to stand apart from the crowd. `;)`

Answer (score 1):

POSIXly:

```
string=bob-type-8.2-mp2-2017-93-43-11-65-48.spr
newstring=${string#"${string%%[0-9]*}"}
newstring=${newstring%.*}
```

- `${string#pattern}`: remove from the start of `$string` what is matched by `pattern` which in this case is:
- `${string%%[0-9]*}` `$string` stripped of its longest trailing part that matches the `[0-9]*` pattern. So that's the part up to the first digit.
- `${newstring%.*}`: `$string` stripped of its *shortest* trailing part that matches the `.*` pattern. So removes the extension.

With `zsh`:

```
newstring=${(M)${string:r}%%[0-9]*}
```

- `${string:r}`: expands to the *root name* (removed the extension) like in `csh`
- `${(M)var%%pattern}`, return what is `M`atched by the `%%` operator (which without `(M)` would remove the longest part at the end that would match the pattern like in POSIX shells).

Answer (score 0):

Sed is one of the possible approaches

```
echo bob-type-8.2-mp2-2017-93-43-11-65-48.spr | sed 's/^[^0-9]*//;s/....$//'
8.2-mp2-2017-93-43-11-65-48
```

regexps mean

1. replace all non-numerical symbols from beginning with nothing till
   the first numerical
2. replace last 4 chars with nothinig

Comment: yep, overseen that, updated now